# Где скачать и как использовать иконки?

Tags: css3, иконки

Чем отличаются иконки от картинок в CSS3?
Где скачать и как использовать иконки?

Comment: Простите, но ничего не понятно. Какие иконки? Svg, font, png? От каких картинок?

Comment: @Виталий Слободянюк скорее всего имеются в виду всякие Font Awesome Icons, glyphicon и т.п.?

Comment: Ищите Font Awesome - попробуйте использовать. После этого с иконками станет всё ясно.